# Spectrum of $A$($x_1$,$x_2$,...) := ($x_3$,$x_2$,$x_1$,$x_6$,$x_5$,$x_4$,$x_9$,$x_8$,$x_7$,...)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A$($x_1$,$x_2$,...) := ($x_3$,$x_2$,$x_1$,$x_6$,$x_5$,$x_4$,$x_9$,$x_8$,$x_7$,...)
define a bounded linear operator on complex space $l^2$. Determine
the spectrum $σ(A)$ and its subsets $σ_p$($A$), $σ_c$($A$), $σ_r$($A$).

I found the eigenvalues of $A$, which I think they are 1 and -1, and I put that $σ_p$($A$)= {-1,1}. I also know that {-1,1} ⊂ $σ(A)$, but I am not able to find the rest of the elements. To find the other subsets I had some complications, because I think that I don´t understand very well their definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $A^2=I.$ Every element $x$ in $\ell^2$ can be decomposed as
$$x=x_{-}+x_+$$ $$x_{-}={1\over 2}(x-Ax),\quad x_+={
1\over 2}(x+Ax).$$
We have $$Ax_-=-x_-\quad Ax_+=x_+ $$
Hence $\sigma(A)=\{1,-1\}=\sigma_p(A).$